# Дженерик и проблема с рекурсией и десериализацией

Tags: java, рекурсия, generics, сериализация, десериализация

У меня есть две DTO

```
public class PersonDto {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    List<PersonDto> childs;
}
```

и

```
public class PersonFullDto extends PersonDto {
    private String parentPhone;
}
```

Хочу что бы когда в **метод поступает строка содержащая json**, то можно было проверить есть ли там значения `parentPhone`?

Если есть, то возвращать `PersonFullDto` иначе `PersonDto` используя для чтения `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`
Что-то вроде этого:

```
T result;
if (json.contains("parentPhone")){
    result = objectMapper.readValue(json, PersonFullDto.class);
    log.info(result.toString());
} else {
    result = objectMapper.readValue(json, PersonDto.class);
    log.info(result.toString());
}
```

Пробовал использовать `Bounded Type Parameter`,

```
public class PersonDto<T extends PersonDto> {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    List<T> childs;
}
```

Но из-за наличия поля `childs` типа `PersonDto` или `PersonFullDto`  возникала рекурсия, проблемы с которой я не смог решить

А если сделать вот так

```
public class PersonDto {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    List<? extends PersonDto> childs;
}
```

то `ObjectMapper` ломается и даже как написать `Custom Deserializer` для такого случая не нашёл

Вот полный код для теста: https://github.com/AlexeyOs/GenericProblem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Основная задача здесь - сделать правильный десериализатор, ключевые моменты прокомментированы в коде:

```java
public class PersonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<PersonDto> {
    public static final String PARENT_PHONE_NODE_NAME = "parentPhone";
    public static final String ID_NODE_NAME = "id";
    public static final String NAME_NODE_NAME = "name";
    public static final String CHILDS_NODE_NAME = "childs";

    @Override
    public PersonDto deserialize(@NotNull JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();

        PersonDto result;
        // разбираемся: если есть поля от "дочернего" объекта - создадим его, иначе - создадим родительский.
        if (node.hasNonNull(PARENT_PHONE_NODE_NAME)) {
            result = new PersonFullDto();
            // и заполним здесь поля, которые не являются унаследованными
            ((PersonFullDto) result).setParentPhone(node.get(PARENT_PHONE_NODE_NAME).asText());
        } else {
            result = new PersonDto();
        }

        // Здесь заполняем все "общие" поля, которые присутствуют в базовом классе.
        result.setId(node.get(ID_NODE_NAME).asInt());
        result.setName(node.get(NAME_NODE_NAME).asText());

        // напоследок - самое интересное
        // заполняем список вложенных элементов, рекурсивно вызывая этот же десериализатор.
        JsonNode childNodes = node.get(CHILDS_NODE_NAME);
        if (Objects.nonNull(childNodes))
            if (childNodes.isArray())
                result.setChilds(
                        StreamSupport.stream(childNodes.spliterator(), false)
                                .map(jsonNode -> {
                                    try {
                                        return ctx.readTreeAsValue(jsonNode, PersonDto.class);
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                    }
                                })
                                .toList()
                );

        return result;
    }
```

Теперь остается только пометить базовую dto аннотацией десериализатора:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonDeserialize(using=PersonDeserializer.class)
public class PersonDto {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    List<PersonDto> childs;
}
```

И можно вызывать слегка измененный (для облегчения работы юнит-тестам) метод сервиса:

```java
public PersonDto jsonParser(String json) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return objectMapper.readValue(json, PersonDto.class);
   }
```

Собственно, сам тест для проверки (поленился - воспользовался уже созданным классом и скопировал в него json-ы из контроллера):

```java
    @Test
    void contextLoads() throws JsonProcessingException {
        PersonDto value = service.jsonParser(personDto);
        assertInstanceOf(PersonDto.class, value);
        assertFalse(value instanceof PersonFullDto);

        value = service.jsonParser(personFullDto);
        assertInstanceOf(PersonFullDto.class, value);
    }
```

Comment: Есть два нюанса. Во первых наличие поля parentPhone со значением null всё же говорит о том, что необходимо создавать ParentFullDto. Поэтому я бы заменил node.hasNonNull() на node.has(). Второй нюанс не совсем ошибка. Коллекция childs может содержать как ParentDto, так и ParentFullDto. Наверное неплохо было бы чтобы объекты были одного типа, т.е. все должны быть ParenfullDto если есть хоть один такой в чайлдах.

Comment: @Serodv С первым, в принципе, согласен... хотя... phone = null, в зависимости от условий задачи, может и не говорить о необходимости создания FullDto. Второе... тоже зависит от реальной задачи, в частности - в коде гитхаба прослеживалось, что childs могут быть любого типа

Comment: Да я и не спорю. Нюанс != Ошибка. Работа приучила смотреть немного шире чем ТЗ, дабы потом не переделывать)

Comment: Может некорректно описал вопрос, но логика действительно такая : `все childs должны быть ParenfullDto если есть хоть один такой в childs`